# phpMyAdmin only works when /etc/php.ini is non-existent

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin

I just set up phpMyAdmin3 with Nginx, and php-fcgi on PHP 5.3.8. Everything works perfectly when I rename php.ini to php.ini.disabled.

I get a generic error that says "Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly." when I run phpMyAdmin while php.ini is in tact.

When I run phpMyAdmin's index.php from the command line, it gives me the expected response: an html page saying "Wrong username/password. Access denied."

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where to look or what configuration option would probably be messed up in php.ini?

Comment: I'd start with the error message it gives you. Check you logs, then check the Session settings in the php.ini, along with any permission associated to the file system it shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made any changes to php.ini?  Check your settings with a test php file with the following code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If nothing jumps out at you, try resetting the file.  This [php.ini](http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/php.ini) might work.

If your really having trouble, consider reinstalling everything (assuming your not on a public server).  A clean install of PHP and phpMyAdmin should fix any problems you may have.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to php.ini. This is a fresh install of phpMyAdmin3, and PHP 5.3.8.

I'll give that php.ini a shot!

Comment: PS - I did a vimdiff to non-working file to functional file and there were too many deltas to easily pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with disabling the APC settings in your php.ini and setting a valid session.save_path in your config. If phpMyAdmin it's usually because APC is enabled (and that's a problem combined with phpMyAdmin) or the sessions can't be saved locally.